# Preselect checkbox using ionic 4, angular 8.3 and sqlite

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using angular 8.3, ionic 4.  I cannot get the checkbox to be pre-selected (checked).  They all appear as unchecked.  The data coming from sqlite is mixed (some true, some false).  Here is the ion-content:

```
<ion-content>
  <form *ngIf="frmEventTab" [formGroup]="frmEventTab">
    <ion-grid>
      <div *ngFor="let work of works; let i=index">
          <ion-col col-1 size="2" class="ion-text-center" text-align: center>
            <ion-checkbox formControlName="chkConfirmed" (ionChange)="onChange(work.workId, 'chkConfirmed', $event.checked)" value="work.confirmed"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </div>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the ts code, as you can see, I am loading the data in setupWorks().

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Work } from '../classes/work';

// Import Services
import { WorkService } from '../classes/work.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  works: Work[];               // List of all Works
  frmEventTab: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private ws: WorkService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.setupWorks();

  }

  createForm() {

    // Setup Validators
    this.frmEventTab = this.formBuilder.group({
      chkConfirmed: new FormControl()
    });

  }

  setupWorks()
  {
    this.ws
        .getWorkByEventId(1, 1)
        .subscribe((data: Work[]) => {

        // Save incoming data
        this.works = data;

        // Create Form (once we have retrieved the data)
        this.createForm();

    });
  }

  // Checkbox change
  onChange(workId, checkboxType, isChecked) {

    if(isChecked) {
      var x = 0;
    }

 }


}
```

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `true` value to the `FormControl` where you want it to be checked:

```
this.frmEventTab = this.formBuilder.group({
    chkConfirmed: new FormControl(true),
});
```

Comment: Hi igor_c thank you for your post.  That does not work however.  That code ends up checking all of them.  I would like to check them based on the value in "work.confirmed".  Please take a look at the html for the checkbox: value="work.confirmed".  They should only be checked based on work.confirmed.

Comment: @RobertSmith you shouldn't pass a value in that way as you're using reactive form approach. The initial value should be set in the .ts file. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  Is there a way I can set the value in the html?  I would rather have it all there since I have the for loop in the html already.  Otherwise I have code in two places.

Comment: You can use template driven form https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Thank you igor_c.  What would be involved in using template drive with a for loop?  (Since I will be displaying multiple records).  I will also have more than one type of checkbox for each item in "work". I just simplified it in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The fix is to not use the **formControlName** tag or **value** tag on the checkbox.  Also send the whole $event back in the onChange:

```
<ion-checkbox [checked]="work.confirmed" (ionChange)="onChange(work.workId, 'chkConfirmed', $event)"></ion-checkbox>
```

In the onChange method, here is how you check if it is selected:

```
onChange(workId, checkboxType, isChecked) {
    if(isChecked.detail.checked) {
      // its checked!
    }
}
```

This works perfect for setting the current value from the database (during form creation) and then updating the value in the onChange method.

Note: This is using reactive forms (not template driven forms)

Note #2: This is a "hack" solution since removal from formControlName will cause it's value and the value of all the other controls to not be available.  So you would have to create an update statement in sqlite to only update the current checkbox that is being changed.  (Since the values of the other ones would not be stored in the FormGroup).

Or you could pass the object to get all the values for that record as follows:

```
<ion-checkbox [checked]="work.confirmed" (ionChange)="onChange(work, 'chkConfirmed', $event)"></ion-checkbox>
```

Notice the onChange event now passes the whole record: work (Instead of just passing the work.workId.) Now you would have all the other fields for this record available.

If anyone knows a better way to do all of this using reactive forms, please let me know.

Reference:

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/forms-and-validation-in-ionic